# MAX31855K reported temp dropping when AC current applied at ktype thermocouple location

Tags: raspberry-pi, pid-controller, thermocouple

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi, MAX31855K thermocouple amplifier, and solid state relay to control an espresso machine's boiler using a PID.

However I'm hitting a frustrating snag. I have everything hooked up and temps are reported properly (I'm reading temps using python libraries off the Pi). Heating up the probe reports a higher temperature, and vice versa, so I know the leads are hooked up properly.

The problem happens when I plug the espresso machine in the wall. The MAX31855K immediately starts reporting a temperature ~20F too low (instant temperature read drop). As soon as I unplug the machine, the temp returns to its accurate value.

I was using this thermocouple (http://www.auberins.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=307) which has a stainless steel sleeve, and appears to be a "grounded" thermocouple, which apparently the MAX31855K doesn't support - even though I'm following plans made by someone who used this thermocouple succesfully.

Fair enough, I bought a new k type thermocouple that is ungrounded - and same issue!!

At this point, I don't know what to do. Could the MAX31855K breakout board be defective? Anything else I could check? Here's a circuit diagram:

[image: circuit diagram]

Thanks!

Comment: You have some high-frequency cross-talk between your heater and thermocouple. The ripples are getting rectified somewhere at amplifier input causing parasitic offset.

Comment: Add a ceramic capacitor across the leads to reduce AC noise? Never tried it with a thermocouple, but it should work, as long as the leakage is low...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried adding a 0.10uF capacitor across the thermocouple leads, but unfortunately that did not seem to have any effect.